# Display my answers on my blog

Tags: support, answers, feed

How do I get the answers I've posted on these sites to display on my blog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check out [Stack2Blog](https://stackapps.com/questions/611/stack2blog-turning-your-answers-into-blogs-source-code-released).  It's an app written using the Stack Exchange API.

It's purpose is for turning good answers into blog posts.

Comment: i have blog on blogspot.com how cna i do that ?

Comment: @pranay read the page. `Visit the homepage, enter your StackOverflow user id, and you'll be presented with a list of all your StackOverflow answers. You can then copy the answer (formatted for easy WordPress pasting), and we'll remember that this answer has already been copied to your blog.`

Comment: @pranay the directions are in the link.

Answer (score 2):

You could parse [your RSS Feed](https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/user/314488) and display only the items starting with "Answer by".

Comment: not geeting you how can i get RSS feed

Comment: i have to paste this on my blog page ? will it work ?

Comment: i have blog on blogspot.com

Comment: @pranay nope, this would take some programming.